Padding in blob chunks?
I was going through ethereum blobs trying to calculate how much of the data space is actually used. I understand that when the space of a blob is not filled, it is padded with zeros to the end of the 128 kb.
But oftentimes there are 32b chunks in the middle of the blob containing mostly or only zeros, like 0000000000000000a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.
Is that 1 byte of information and 31 bytes of padding or is there more information in there?

What is your question?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
